# Remember the former input in SharePoint list

Tags: retention

There is always a `remember function` within my SharePoint `list` so everytime I add a new item, I don't need to repeatedly input the same content since the system will remember the first input and then every time I enter the first word, it shows the possible match automatically. But after modifying some columns, I lost the function, I used to think there is something wrong with cookie in my IE, but change to another browser doesn't solve the problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you explain more how your remember function works and what changes you made to which columns?